# Create JSON file and display

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I want to create a JSON file based in MySQL data but for some reasons my code is not working at all(I dont have any errors)

```
$results= $panel->query('SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetch_all();

$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$file = 'servers.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

What I want:

```
{
    "ID": [
      "IPOFTHESERVERFROMDATABASE",
      PORTFROMDATABASE,
      "NAMEFROMDATABASE"
    ],
..
}
```

What I'm getting:

```
[["ID","NAME","IP","PORT","RCON"]]
```

Comment: _And I wanted to the output would be like this:..._ And how is the output currently?

Comment: @B001ᛦ currently not working and I have no idea why so I have no output..

Comment: Well basically because you dont put ANYTHING in `$data`

Comment: Should I use something like this? 
    $data[] = array($id, $name, $ip, $port, $rcon_pw);

Comment: "I dont have any errors" http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php .. besides use the error functions of the database api to get the error from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not putting anything into the `$data` array.

Change the code as below to load the rows into the `$data` array before `json_encode()`ing it

```
$results= $panel->query('SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetch_all();

$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$file = 'servers.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

Or as Ray says below, as you have used a `fetchAll` you could probably do without the foreach loop and do

```
$results= $panel->query('SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetch_all();

$json_string = json_encode($results);
$file = 'servers.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

#### EDIT: The output you wanted?

You say you want

```
{
    "ID": [
            "IP",
            PORT,
            "NAME"
    ],
    "ID": [
            "IP",
            PORT,
            "NAME"
    ]
}
```

which of course is not possible as you have 2 keys/properties with the same name i.e. `"ID"`

```
$results= $panel->query('SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetch_all();

$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[$row[0]] = [$row[2],$row[3],$row[1]];
}
$json_string = json_encode($data);
$file = 'servers.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

Comment: "You are not putting anything into the $data array." nice catch +1 i didn't notice it geuss i need some more coffee.. i assuming the topicstarter is using somekind of framework where `fetch_all()` directly returns a data array like `mysqli_fetch_*` functions does in that case the foreach loop is unnecessary,, And you can directly do `$json_string = json_encode($results);` or `$json_string = json_encode($panel->query('SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY id ASC;')->fetch_all());`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Hmm, you may well have a very good point there Ray

Comment: @RaymondNijland Im getting no data, just this in file []

Comment: Which version of the answer are you using

Comment: @RiggsFolly im using Ray's

Comment: And have you checked that your query actually returns any data

Comment: @RiggsFolly im getting this output  [["5","name","ip","port","rcon"]] but I didn't want this output but 1 like I put up

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, that last code that you just wrote works just fine ;)